On a trigonometric inequality by Huygens
The following inequality, ascribed to Huygens, appeared in this post:
\begin{equation*}
    1-\frac43\,\frac{\sin^3\theta/2}{\theta-\sin\theta}
    >(1-\cos\theta/2)\Big(\frac35-\frac3{1400}\frac{\pi^2}{n^2}\Big), \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
where $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$ and $n$ is an integer $\ge2$.
Later, this inequality was changed to its opposite.
Note that neither the strict inequality \eqref{10} nor its strict opposite hold for $\theta=0$.
It was also said that "the inequality as stated here is the beginning of the asymptotic expansion of the quotient of the left-hand side by the trigonometric function on the right".
The mysterious role of $n$ here has not been explained. However, one has
\begin{equation*}
    f(\theta):=\Big(1-\frac43\,\frac{\sin^3\theta/2}{\theta-\sin\theta}\Big)
    \Big/(1-\cos\theta/2)
    =\frac35-\frac{3\theta^2}{1400}-\frac{11\theta^4}{336000}+O(\theta^6). 
\end{equation*}
So, it makes sense to ask if
\begin{equation*}
    f(\theta)<\frac35-\frac{3\theta^2}{1400} \quad\text{for }\theta\in(0,\pi/2]. \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}
It will be shown below that this is indeed true.

$\renewcommand{\th}{\theta}$As in the previous answer, use the substitution
$$t=\tan\frac\th4,\quad \sin\frac\th2=\frac{2t}{1+t^2},
\quad \cos\frac\th2=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},
\quad \sin\th=\frac{4t(1-t^2)}{(1+t^2)^2},
\quad \th=4\tan^{-1}t$$
in this case to rewrite the inequality \eqref{20} in question as
\begin{equation*}
    g(t):=36 \tan^{-1}(t)^3-\frac{36 (1-t^2) t \tan^{-1}(t)^2}{\left(t^2+1\right)^2}
    +\frac{105 \left(5-t^2\right) \tan^{-1}(t)}{t^2}-\frac{35 \left(3 t^4+22 t^2+15\right)}{t \left(t^2+1\right)^2}<0   \tag{30}\label{30}
\end{equation*}
for all
\begin{equation*}
    t\in(0,t_*],\quad t_*:=\tan\frac\pi8=\sqrt{2}-1. 
\end{equation*}
Let
\begin{equation*}
    g_1(t):=g'(t)\frac{\left(t^2+1\right)^3}{t^4+6 t^2+1} \\ 
    =72 \tan ^{-1}(t)^2
    -\frac{6 \left(163 t^6+537
   t^4+525 t^2+175\right) \tan ^{-1}(t)}{t^3 \left(t^4+6 t^2+1\right)}
   +\frac{70 \left(33 t^4+40 t^2+15\right)}{t^2 \left(t^4+6 t^2+1\right)}, 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    g_2(t)&:=g_1'(t)\frac{t^4 \left(t^2+1\right) \left(t^4+6 t^2+1\right)^2}{187 t^{12}+1084
   t^{10}+6903 t^8+15784 t^6+15937 t^4+6300 t^2+525} \\ 
   &=6 \tan ^{-1}(t)-\frac{2 t \left(2799 t^{10}+12455 t^8+34970 t^6+41826 t^4+18375
   t^2+1575\right)}{187 t^{12}+1084 t^{10}+6903 t^8+15784 t^6+15937 t^4+6300
   t^2+525}, 
\end{aligned}   
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    g_3(t)&:=g_2'(t)\frac{\left(t^2+1\right) \left(187 t^{12}+1084 t^{10}+6903 t^8+15784 t^6+15937
   t^4+6300 t^2+525\right)^2}{192 t^8} \\ 
   &=6545 t^{16}+59300 t^{14}+36012 t^{12}-912092 t^{10}-2894890 t^8-3467092
   t^6 \\
   &-1800788 t^4-362100 t^2-24255<0 
\end{aligned}   
\end{equation*}
for $t\in(0,t_*]$.
Also, $g_2(0)=g_1(0+)=g(0+)=0$.
So, \eqref{30} immediately follows. $\quad\Box$

Answering one's own questions is "always explicitly encouraged". Moreover, the asker is prompted by the system to right away share knowledge and answer the question.

The question states that it makes sense to ask if
\begin{equation}
    f(\theta)<\frac35-\frac{3\theta^2}{1400} \quad\text{for }\theta\in(0,\pi/2].
\end{equation}
However, this is the wrong question.
The right question is to ask if
\begin{equation*}
    f(\theta)<c \quad\text{for }\theta\in(0,\pi/2],
\end{equation*}
with \begin{equation}
    c=\frac35-\frac{3(\pi/2)^2}{1400},
\end{equation}
which happens to be false:
\begin{equation}
    f(1)-c=0.003112,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
f(\pi/2)-c=-0.000201.
\end{equation}
